# How to set font color for a particular column in list view?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

How to set font color for a particular column in list view?
I have two columns in listview, and I want to set the font in 2nd column to red color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ListView.DrawColumnHeader` Event

```
private void listView1_DrawColumnHeader(object sender, DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventArgs e)
    {
            // Draw the header text. 
            using (Font headerFont =
                        new Font("Helvetica", 10, FontStyle.Bold, FontColor.Red))
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Header.Text, headerFont, 
                        Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, sf);
            }
    }
```